# Throttle piped command on OSX?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, throttling

I want to throttle output from `grep` to run at most every X seconds.  Specifically I want to do something like this:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | grep "No route to host" | throttle 3s | xargs -I % sh -c 'reset wifi'
```

Comment: No, you want to reset WiFi if... See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski -- No, I want to know how to throttle a command.  I know exactly what the actual problem and solution are and laying out the problem in 75 steps just to be lead back to *this exact question* is pointless and a waste of everyone's time.  Don't assume that everyone is ignorant about their own questions without even asking a question yourself.  It's just rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, based on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378334/how-do-i-throttle-how-frequently-lines-of-output-are-passed-on), but slightly changed for OSX:

```
epoch () { date -v+$* "+%s" }

interval () {
    INTERVAL="$*"
    WHEN_TO_RUN=0
    while read LINE; do
        if (( $(epoch 0S) >= $WHEN_TO_RUN )) then
            echo $LINE
            WHEN_TO_RUN="$(epoch $INTERVAL)"
        fi
    done
}
```

which allows `... | interval 3S`

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. But there seems to be a syntax problem - no semicolon after the arithmetic evaluation (the pair of right parens). Also, LAST_RUN_AT is unused, and of course the basic timing here is pretty coarse, the granularity being whole seconds. But if quality of the pass-through serves the need of the task at hand, see if you can accept your own answer. :-)

Comment: @sjnarv -- If you know how to get epoch time in ms I'll update it to make it more generic

Comment: No, I don't have a solution that would be easy for macOS. To be fair, I haven't looked much, so don't take this as definitive info. I have noted that something pretty easy for Linux - pulling a "since the epoch" value that includes nanoseconds via something like `date +%s.%N` - just isn't supported on macOS (as far as I know, anyway). If I needed a little more accuracy on the intervals on macOS, I might write some C that used `gettimeofday(2)`.